# C++ cross-platform archive manipulation/display

Tags: c++, zip, cross-platform, archive

Are there any cross-platform C++ libraries that can do the following?

- View files in an archive
- extract individual files to memory
- add/remove/rename files in the archive (excluding rar for licensing reasons)
- compatible with zip, rar, and 7zip archives

I'm using Qt, so it looks like QuaZIP is a possible choice for zip files, but I'm unsure about rar and 7zip.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could use **libarchive** , Here is the official [project page](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive) .

If you are doing this in Qt , Then Try using my library which wraps libarchive to support the Qt Event loop. Here is **QArchive** [project page](https://antony-jr.github.io/QArchive)